# Byobu: kill warning

Tags: byobu

Short question: is there anyway to get `Byobu` to present warnings questions, perhaps in the form `Are you sure you want to kill X? y/n` when killing windows/panes/splits etc.?

Comment: Well, a function that asks for user confirmation could be placed into `.bashrc`, but that will only work locally, won't work over ssh.

Comment: @Serg Great. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Using `screen` as backend for `byobu` allows you to use <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> shortcut for killing windows , allows you to have a `Really kill this window [y/n]` confirmation message.

The screen bellow shows this functionality. The command actually ran is `byobu-screen`. You can alias `byobu` to `byobu-screen` to avoid running `byobu-screen` each time, but it may lead to confusion.

[image]

Comment: looks good. how about with `tmux`?